# What do these question marks mean in the code

Tags: php

What does the "?" mean in code laravel like this?

```
 $followers = $actionRequest->followers ? [
   'instagram' => $actionRequest->followers?->instagram,
    'tiktok' => $actionRequest->followers?->tiktok,
 ] : null;
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as not to mislead SO users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the ternary operator. It is a conditional operator just like "if".

Given that the first operand evaluates true, evaluate as second operand, else evaluate as third operand.

This means the code will load the followers into the variable $followers if $actionRequest->followers which might be a boolean is true but will be assigned null

Note:
?-> is null safe operator. Which is a different operator altogether

Comment: There are 3 question marks in the code, does this apply to all 3 of them?

Comment: Yeah just realized that now.

Comment: It is a null safe operator. Trying to prevent error in case there is a null value for instagram or tiktok

Comment: Indeed here's some documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe

Comment: Well in my last comment. if the $actionRequest->followers does not have the attribute instagram or tiktok it will not give an error. It is used in the situation where $actionRequest->followers? could have one, both attributes or none at all.

Answer (score -1):

this is called ternary operation.

```
$x = condition ? expr2 : expr3 ;
```

the value of `$x` is `expr2` if `condition` is true
and `expr3` if `condition` is false .

so in your example the value of  `$followers` if `$actionRequest->followers` is true,  is

`[ 'instagram' => $actionRequest->followers?->instagram, 'tiktok' => $actionRequest->followers?->tiktok, ]`

, unless it return `null`.

Comment: There are 3 question marks in the code, does this apply to all 3 of them?

Comment: ` 'instagram' => $actionRequest->followers?->instagram,` has wrong syntax. I think some part of it is removed.

Comment: It's not wrong, it the new nullsafe operator, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe